# Constructing graph of crypto financial instruments 2016-2017

Tags: classification, graphs, distribution, finance

Set of financial instruments represent the set of vertices of the graph. For any pair of vertices $i$ and $j$, an edge connecting them is added to the graph if the corresponding correlation coefficient  $C_{ij}$ based on the price  fluctuations of instruments $i$ and $j$ is greater than or equal to a specified threshold $\theta, (\theta ∈ [ − 1; 1])$.

([Reference](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167947304000258))

1. Finding correlation
2. Degree of distribution
3. Analysis of cliques and independent sets in the market graph

I am wondering how to achieve the above? I am willing to understand the internal structure of the market.

Answer (score 1):

1. Finding correlation - It has been described in the provided reference
2. Degree of distribution - Every decent package in which you build the network will have a function that will calculate the empirical distribution of the vertex degrees.
3. Analysis of cliques and independent sets in the market graph - This is a problem of Graph Clustering. There are many methods available. Start by reading [this](http://www.leonidzhukov.net/hse/2015/networks/papers/GraphClustering_Schaeffer07.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to build the above equation on R using cryptocurrency market data.

Comment: There is a package called [igraph](http://igraph.org/r/) where you can build your network and easily calculate [degree distribution](http://igraph.org/r/doc/degree.html) and proceed with [Graph Clustering/community detection](http://igraph.org/r/doc/communities.html).